# How to get devise to work with accepts_nested_attributes_for in a has one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, nested-attributes, has-one

I am trying to get my user form to also allow the user to fill out their company profile at the same time via form_for. For some reason it is not showing the company fields. Here is my code for the controller and layouts.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_attributes

  has_one :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # Validation
  validates :name, :presence => true
end

<%= f.fields_for :company do |company_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= company_form.label :name, "Company Name" %><br />
    <%= company_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `company` attribute of the `User` should be not-`nil`, so either in the controller or in the form, create it:

```
<% user.build_company if user.company.nil? %>
<%= f.fields_for :company do |company_form| %>
...
```

Comment: Should probably do that in User#after_initialize

Answer (score 5):

It might be better to do this in the model rather than the view or the controller.

```
class User
  # Blah blah blah
  def profile
    super || build_profile
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm working with Devise and I don't know that I can do a `resource.build_profile` in the RegistrationsController, so this worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution from Zabba only worked for me with:

```
<% @user.build_profile if @user.profile.nil? %>
```

Othwerise, the view had no idea what "user" is