# Devise Signup, create a has_one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to create a Provider record when  a user signs up using devise.   I have set it up as per:
[Devise: User belongs_to organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987015/devise-user-belongs-to-organization)

however no provider is created.  What could i be doing wrong?

User has_one Provider.
I modified my signup form:

```
<%= fields_for :provider do |provider_fields| %>
      <%= provider_fields.label :name, :label => 'Company Name' %>
      <%= provider_fields.text_field :name %>
 <% end %>
```

And my model

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name,  :provider_attributes
    belongs_to :provider
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :provider
```

I can see in the rails s output:

```
 "provider"=>{"name"=>"kjhkjh"},
```

amongst the user attributes when i submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha!  Self rescue.  : )

Seems it's necessary to create the provider model if its nil so the helper knows what to make (or something)

so I added this to the model:

```
 def provider
    super || build_provider
  end
```

[How to get devise to work with accepts_nested_attributes_for in a has one relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424223/how-to-get-devise-to-work-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for-in-a-has-one-relati)

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't see the full user registration form to determine what block variable you are passing into the form builder, I'll assume it's `|f|`. If so, you need to prefix `f` to `fields_for`.

```
f.fields_for :provider
```

This way, you are passing `:provider_attributes` in your params, not simply provider. I see that you have already added `:provider_attributes` to attr_accessible (another common gotcha), so now you just need to be sure that is what your passing!

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: Thank you.  When i make that change, the provider name field disappears altogether. Looking in browser tools, it isn't outputting anything at all when set like that. Might I have gotten something else  wrong thats upsetting it?

Comment: So googling around what is likely to cause that seems to be: <% needs to be <%= /  use the right instance variable (provider_fields) / make sure accepts_nested_attributes_for :provider is set in the model.  All of which i have done.  Missing something.